# _id field serialized as null when using an interface in dotnet mongodb driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a setup which requires me to rely on an interface to create my `IMongoCollection`. Basically the objects I’m persisting are using generics so I cannot use a class in `GetCollection<>`.

I have a custom discriminator which i register with the interface and all possible generics like this:

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention(typeof(IMyClass), new MyClassConvention());

foreach (var type in genericOptions) {
    var genType = typeof(MyClass<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    BsonSerializer.RegisterDiscriminatorConvention(genType, new MyClassConvention());
}
```

The object has a string Id field which i expect to be auto filled by the mongo driver. However the serializer now becomes `DiscriminatedInterfaceSerializer` which does not implement the interface IBsonIdProvider.

Can someone tell me what the best approach is for my setup? I would like to rely on the default serialization as the rest of my object is serialized and deserialized properly, however its just persisting the _id field as null.

I couldnt register a custom serializer as its evaluating it for the interface only. I tried adding it to the ClassMap, but its already registered after registering the DiscriminatorConvention.

When I use `[BsonIgnoreIfDefault]` the id field does not get serialized as null and mongodb sets the id but it is not updated in the in memory object after the InsertOne call.

Comment: I would still like an answer, however for now I've solved it by changing the interface to be an abstract class.